# How can I round up a number without php function ceil

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a function that output will be rounded up number. I know there is a php function, but I want to make this function for another purpose.

Comment: You can also use `round` in php

Comment: Do you want algorithm for rounding numbers? I don't think this is language-related question.

Comment: I have no idea why you want to reimplement this from scratch, but in any case: what have you tried? Also, what is the question?

Comment: Rounding up is somewhat vague. Do you rounding towards positive infinity? Or rounding away from zero?

Comment: and may we know that purpose so we can help.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want ceil without using ceiling...

```
intval($number + .5)
```

this is the same thing, but you are still using a built in function.

EDIT:  apparently the above solution does **not** work as I intended it to in PHP.  You can use the round function to similar effect

```
round($number + .5)
```

or something similar to another answer:

```
$n = intval($number + .5);
if($n < $number){
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, never thought of it like that :-)

Comment: I used to do something similar in AS3 I dont remember why.  I would really like to know why the questioner wants this.  this method would surely have similar overhead to the `ceil` function.

Comment: `echo ceil(2.1) . "\t" . intval(2.1 + 0.5);` gives `3 2`.

Answer (score 1):

May this do it?

```
function newceil($num)
{
    $re=intval($num);
    if($re<$num) $re++;
    return $re
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cut off the fractional part by casting it to an integer and afterwards check, whether the so derived value is smaller or even the initial value.

```
$input = 3.141592653;
$intVersion = (int) $input;
if($intVersion<$input) $intVersion++;
return $intVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round up/down 
You can use `round` method

```
/* Using PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP with 1 decimal digit precision */
 echo round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   //  1.6
 echo round( 1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   //  1.5
 echo round(-1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // -1.6
 echo round(-1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // -1.5

 /* Using PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN with 1 decimal digit precision */
 echo round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //  1.5
 echo round( 1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //  1.5
 echo round(-1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // -1.5
 echo round(-1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // -1.5

 /* Using PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN with 1 decimal digit precision */
echo round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //  1.6
echo round( 1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //  1.5
echo round(-1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // -1.6
echo round(-1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // -1.5

/* Using PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD with 1 decimal digit precision */
echo round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  //  1.5
echo round( 1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  //  1.5
echo round(-1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // -1.5
echo round(-1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // -1.5
?>
```

**Note: ceil round up**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round()` and `floor()` and `number_format()` for round up number.

```
echo round(153.751);     // 154
echo floor(153.751); // 153
echo number_format(153.751); // 154
```